# Flex container width fit content width

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bulma

Having issues fitting parent flex container width to a child's flex container content width.

Using Bulma, I have the following HTML structure

```css
    .signup-form {
      display:inline-flex;
      align-items: center;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="body">
    <div class="is-active modal">
    
        <div class="modal-background">
        </div>
    
        <div class="modal-card signup-form">

          <header class="modal-card-head has-text-centered">
            <button class="delete"></button>
            <p class="modal-card-title">Title</p>
          </header>
    
          <section class="modal-card-body">
            <input class="input" placeholder="Name"/ >
            <input class="input" placeholder="Phone Number"/ >
            <input class="input" placeholder="Email"/ >
            <input class="input" placeholder="Address"/ >
          </section>
    
          <footer class="modal-card-foot">
            <nav class="page-control level has-text-centered is-mobile">
              <a class="button is-small is-info">
                Next
              </a>
            </nav>
          </footer>
    
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

But it ends up applying to all children flex containers, as you can see here:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mWqRxW

How do I fix this, and make the parent flex container fit to the width of the child flex container (in this case the width of the inputs)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The container will not shrink-wrap the input elements when it has `width: 640px`.

Remove the fixed width.

[**revised codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GWOWGY)

Comment: Obviously I tried that. That's not what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to get the whole container to fit the width of the inputs.

Comment: Then obviously you shouldn't be using `width: 640px` on `.modal-card`. Switch that to `auto`. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GWOWGY

Comment: Understood. But as you can see, the container cannot be shorter than 640px. You can either shrink the container or expand the inputs to cover the full width.

Comment: Yes. Thanks. Works

Answer (score -2):

You just need to add:

```
header,
footer{
  width: 100%;
}
```

So it takes all the width available. Is that what you wanted or am I mising something?

Comment: Yeah no the question is a little more sophisticated than that

Comment: Could you explain your questions a little better then please?

Comment: No man. Why are you hardcoding the width? This is bad practice.

Comment: You were hardcoding the input width, so there is where your problems starts maybe. Was that the "desired" output, putting the hardcoded widths aside ofc, is was just for testing.